# Merge line with previous if new line starts with "|" pipe in dataframe

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, row

Considering the below text scenario:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dummy.txt', sep='|')
        ID   Name           Email Country  Quantity
0  2.0  name2  name@email.com      UK       8.0
1  3.0  name3  name@email.com     NaN       NaN
2  NaN     UK               8     NaN       NaN
3  5.0  name4  name@email.com     NaN       NaN
4  NaN     UK               8     NaN       NaN
5  7.0  name5  name@email.com      UK       8.0
```

and raw data is:

```
ID|Name|Email|Country|Quantity
2|name2|name@email.com|UK|8
3|name3|name@email.com
|UK|8
5|name4|name@email.com
|UK|8
7|name5|name@email.com|UK|8
```

So there is a broken line with a "|". The logic should be: if line starts with a "|" then merge with previous line where it belongs

The result should be:

```
ID|Name|Email|Country|Quantity
2|name2|name@email.com|UK|8
3|name3|name@email.com|UK|8
5|name4|name@email.com|UK|8
7|name5|name@email.com|UK|8
```

The Linux code does the job:

`sed -z 's/\n|/|/g`

However, I am not able to do this in Python.

Answer (score 3):

Use `re` module ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XYqaRK/1)):

```
txt = '''ID|Name|Email|Country|Quantity
2|name2|name@email.com|UK|8
3|name3|name@email.com
|UK|8
5|name4|name@email.com
|UK|8
7|name5|name@email.com|UK|8'''

import re

txt = re.sub(r'\n\|', '|', txt)
print(txt)
```

Prints:

```
ID|Name|Email|Country|Quantity
2|name2|name@email.com|UK|8
3|name3|name@email.com|UK|8
5|name4|name@email.com|UK|8
7|name5|name@email.com|UK|8
```

---

To load as pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep='|')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID   Name           Email Country  Quantity
0   2  name2  name@email.com      UK         8
1   3  name3  name@email.com      UK         8
2   5  name4  name@email.com      UK         8
3   7  name5  name@email.com      UK         8
```

---

EDIT: To read from file, you can use:

```
import re
import sys
import pandas as pd

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:  # Not named on 2.6
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

with open('dummy.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    txt = f_in.read()

txt = re.sub(r'\n\|', '|', txt)

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep='|')

print(df)  # or 'print df' in Python2
```

Prints:

```
   ID   Name           Email Country  Quantity
0   2  name2  name@email.com      UK         8
1   3  name3  name@email.com      UK         8
2   5  name4  name@email.com      UK         8
3   7  name5  name@email.com      UK         8
```

Comment: Thanks! I am actually querying data from Athena and the data is return as a dataframe already. When I apply this regex, the following error is returned: ypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.

Comment: @Sama So the broken string is in some column/cell? If yes, you need to access it before supplying it to `re.sub`

Comment: I think I am able to access it as I assign add 'Nan' values. The above data is dummy data however the logic and issue are the same. Your solution is for raw data, then putting it in a dataframe.

Comment: @Sama I think I don't quite  understand, can you edit your question and put the dataframe there? So I can see it...

Comment: Considering the above changes, the solution does not work on dataframes.

Comment: @Sama I added to my answer how to read the broken CSV from file.

Comment: Hello @Andrej, supposing the data comes out from a dataframe already, i.e. not having access to the txt file, is it possible to do the same operation? Many thanks!